# Defining genres

Tags: discussion, genre

A while back I asked about [What Genre is This](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/are-what-genre-is-this-questions-on-topic) questions.  Looking back on this and thinking about [Adrian's recent answer](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/are-what-genre-is-this-questions-on-topic/211#211), it seems like we could do something to address genres.  I've seen genre-related questions on several sites and forums, so there is some demand.  However, I still feel like trying to pigeonhole the original poster's story is of limited value, as it's very specific (too localized?), somewhat subjective, and has limited value to the community - the next person asking the question will want to know about their own story, not someone else's.

I think questions like "What are common attributes of genre X?" might be more useful.

- This seems better than "Define genre X," which seems to me to invite answers that try to be a "complete" or "final" definition, and thus, disagreements.  It allows several people to build a cumulative definition.
- It leans toward defining a genre by what it is, rather than what it isn't.  This could be good or bad, but a definition of what something *is* is a lot more concise than a definition of what it *isn't*.
- It invites attributes that can be backed up, so it feels less subjective.  If you say genre X frequently has a particular attribute, you can point to specific works in the genre where that is the case.

One concern I have with these is that we might initially get quite a lot of them and it may feel a bit spammy.  However, if they're useful to the community, that's probably not a big problem.

So, do people think these types of questions would be useful, or not?

Comment: I think questions such as you describe ought to be on-topic, and ones that are close should be edited to what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** What are common attributes of genre X?

**Answer:** [Insert relevant TV Tropes link here.]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for me to view such a question as useful - at least for most genres.

As [TRiG pointed out so succinctly](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/defining-genres/366#366), this question is best answered by a link to TV Tropes or to Wikipedia, which cover these very comprehensively.

These questions also aren't useful because they don't answer any difficulty - who needs to know, without any further purpose or focus, what the attributes of, say, Victorian Steampunk are? It's a terminology debate, not a Q&A.

If somebody knows whether *their story* fits the genre... or *what themes are explored well by this genre*... or *what tropes are already considered overused* within the genre... those are specific, useful, answerable questions. Asking for a debatable definition simply serves no such purpose.

I'm happy to make an exception for genre who's basic definition is unclear or confusing - e.g. [What is Literary Fiction?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-literary-fiction), or Magical Realism, or pretty much any question that makes clear why there's no quick obvious answer (or that such answers are generally unclear and confusing, so a Q&A would be helpful). But I don't see any use in a spate of "What are common attributes of queer romance?" "What are common attributes of legal thrillers?" "What are common attributes of Supernatural YA?".

I will say that in this case, my disinterest might possibly be better represented by downvoting questions I see as unhelpful than by ruling them off-topic. **I guess they're basically on-topic, they just seem to me like bad questions.**